# How do i insert a data into 2 different tables using 1 form in php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

1. This is my receptionistAction.php file that enables me to manipulate the crud functions of my forms.
2. I'm trying to insert the receptionists and its user information into different SQL statement but it results in an error in the system.

   ```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include '../../dbConnect.php';
    $pdo = new dbConnect();
    $tblName = 'receptionist';
    $tblName2 = 'users';
       if(isset($_REQUEST['action_type'])!empty($_REQUEST['action_type'])){
       if($_REQUEST['action_type'] == 'add'){
       $userData = array(

       'Rec_lastName' => $_POST['rlname'],
       'Rec_firstName' => $_POST['rfname'],
       'Rec_contact' => $_POST['rcontact'],
       'Rec_emailAdd' => $_POST['remailAddress'],
       'Rec_gender' => $_POST['rgender']
   );
   $userData2 = array(

       'username' => $_POST['rusername'],
       'password' => md5($_POST['rpassword']),
       'userType' => "receptionist"            
   );
   $insert = $pdo->insert($tblName,$userData);
   $insert2 = $pdo->insert($tblName2,$userData2);
   header("Location:../Maintenance-Receptionists.php");
   ```

This is my code from dbConnect which enables my receptionistAction.php to execute insert function for crud.

```
    public function insert($table,$data){
    if(!empty($data) && is_array($data)){
        $columns = '';
        $values  = '';
        $i = 0;

        $columnString = implode(',', array_keys($data));
        $valueString = ":".implode(',:', array_keys($data));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$columnString.") VALUES 
        (".$valueString.")";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        foreach($data as $key=>$val){
             $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $val);
        }
        $insert = $query->execute();
        return $insert?$this->db->lastInsertId():false;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(isset($_REQUEST['action_type'])!empty($_REQUEST['action_type'])){` is not going to work..

Comment: also your calling `insertRowsJoin` but showing `insert` :/

Answer (score 0):

You  need to change your condition for checking `action_type`. Which will produce the error

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action_type'])!empty($_REQUEST['action_type'])){
```

TO

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action_type']) && !empty($_REQUEST['action_type'])){
```